# Website is being scaled down on iPad to be smaller than viewport

Tags: html, ios, ipad, dom

So this is a really strange one.  My website is smaller than my viewport.  I'm inspecting the dom by plugging my iPad into my mac, and inspecting with safari developer tools. If I hover over the html, or body element, the elements are not filling the width of the viewport.  This is a problem for me as my full width image is not full width! There is a gap of about 10% to the right of the html element.

See attached screenshot of the html element being highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this thanks to [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13510) post.

Add to the meta viewport tag `shrink-to-fit=no`